# Combine logical operators in C

Tags: c, expression, logical-operators

I am wondering how costly is to combine logical operators? What is the best way to combine them?

For example:
What is the difference between following two statements in terms of optimization?

```
1) if((!x || !y || !z) && (a != b)) 
2) if(!( x && y && z) && (a != b))
```

I heard from my peers that you should use ANDing operation more often than ORing operation. I am new to C language. Please someone help me to understand this. Any material or link would also be helpful.

Comment: Just leave it to the compiler. It's probably more efficient in optimising such stuff.

Comment: Bothe are same according to DeMorgan's law.

Comment: Please be aware of the [short circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) rule for evaluating conditional expressions in C. If the the entire conditional can be known without evaluating further expressions, they are skipped. So beware of any side-effects that you might expect to happen, but do not (may be a value change or a function call). The direct answer is to write the conditional in the clearest way that will be understood the most easily: when you look at it next year.

Comment: Compilers are pretty smart. On lowest optimization levels it generates [equivalent code](https://godbolt.org/g/tN3469), and when higher levels are used, one version is recognized as being [equivalent to the other](https://godbolt.org/g/lrmroI).

Comment: @WeatherVane - Whenever the first version short circuits, so does the second.

Comment: @StoryTeller thanks, mine was a general comment really.

Comment: You can transform and-expression and to a semantically equivalent or-expression by using negation. If a condition has multiple conditions connected via an and, it can faster be checked since the overall condition is false if at least one of its conditions is false. However, I would focus on readability since this can easily be optimized by a complier.

Comment: @WeatherVane - which why I `+1`'ed it. But in this particular case one need not worry.

Comment: Thanks Weather and StoryTeller. I got it now. Thanks for prompt help.

Comment: It may not be correct but the 1) has to perform 7 logical operation 2) has to perform only five.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless this code is in an *extremely* hot path of your code, always choose the form that is the most logical to a future reader.

If it *is* in a hot path, compile both and look at the assembly. One good tool that let's you see the output for many compilers and CPUs is [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org)

Here's an example testing your scenario: [fiddle](https://godbolt.org/g/DmzWy2)

As you can see, the number of instructions are same.

Answer (score 3):

They both are the same and should not affect the performance. They are equivalents of each other according to [De Morgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws).